# What did Bilbo's cryptic birthday message mean?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

What did Bilbo mean when he said

> I don't know half of you half as well as I should like; and I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve.

Is this a compliment or an insult? The other Hobbits didn't seem to know either.

Comment: Similar post on another stack; [Meaning and interpretation of Bilbo's “half as well” quote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310592/meaning-and-interpretation-of-bilbos-half-as-well-quote/310605)

Answer (score 13):

As covered in the post linked by @Valorum, Bilbo has been intentionally difficult and tried to confuse his guests.

Sentence by sentence it means

> I don't know half of you half as well as I should like

Bilbo wishes he knew half the people at the party better (specifically twice as much as he knows them now). This is a compliment saying that this half of people are worthy of more recognition, but Bilbo hasn't had the opportunity or put in the effort to get to know them

> I like less than half of you half as well as you deserve

He dislikes fewer than half the people in the room more than they really deserve to be disliked (specifically, they deserve to be liked twice as much as they currently at by Bilbo). This could also be a compliment, saying that he's been too pessimistic about his views of this group of people and they deserve more respect from him.

Why he speaks like this is purely to confuse his humble guests and to be polite to them at his farewell. He may not have wanted them to know specifically that he was both complimenting (and possibly insulting them) but he wanted to end his time on a courteous, informative note.

We are never told which groups of people fit into which parts and any guesses would be just that.

Comment: I think you've got the second part backwards - he's saying that he likes less than half of the people *more* than they deserve to be liked. Think of it like this "I like the sackville-baginses 50% more than they deserve to be liked because they are terrible" - that's what he is really saying

Comment: @NKCampbell I disagree. "I like X half as well" means "I like X 0.5t." Adding "as they deserve" makes it "I should be liking X 1t, but I only like them 0,5t". Exactly how the answer explained it.

Comment: @Narusan If t is a negative (he dislikes them), then he could be saying he should dislike them twice as much, but is being kind by disliking them at 50%. Which seems more true to his character, but I don't know if hobbits are that good at maths.

Comment: is the glass half empty or half full? The term 'half' in of itself is ambiguous - you have to look at the context of what he is saying *and* who is there (ie Lobelia and Lotho). The first part is a compliment, the second part is an ambiguous shot at his relatives. The line following says most of the attendees "were trying to work it out and see if it came out to a compliment"

Comment: "I like less than half of you twice as much as you deserve" would be "I like you more than I should.

Comment: half as much - "used for saying that an amount/a number is 50% greater than another amount/number" - http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/half-as-much-many-again

Comment: @NKCampbell thank you for that, but what about "half as well"? I realise I said much instead of well, but that was a mistake on my part. "Half as well" keeps a consistent meaning throughout, I don't see why it would take a conflicting meaning.

Comment: I see your point certainly, but I simply think the full context of the text, especially given the comment "if it came out as a compliment" is meant to imply that it was in fact, not a compliment. Also worth nothing for good or ill - it wasn't until the third draft of this chapter that the term "like" was added to the second part. Up until that point, it was left out, and just said "...know half of you half as well as I should like, and less than half of you half as well as you deserve"